# Wordpress comments - delimiter "/" not found

Tags: comments, warnings

I'm using WordPress comments as a "chat". Not real time chat, it's more like comments with more flow.

But when 4-5 or more members are using coments at the same time, I get this message:

[image]

Not sure why this happens or if its because more than one user is using it at the same time.

Is there anyone here who had the same problem or could lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a soloution and what causes it.
It was not really the delimiter that was the problem it was becasue a user made duplicate posts.

**Solution:**
*Replace*

```
$notify_message .=  preg_replace('#[\s]+#', ' ',sprintf(    get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'title',1))) .' skrev:'. "\r\n" .       $comment->comment_content . "\r\n\r\n";
```

***With***

```
$notify_message =  preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ',sprintf( get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'title',1)) .' skrev:'. "\r\n" . $comment->comment_content . "\r\n\r\n");
```

**And add following code to function.php in your theme, that will allow same user to make dubplacte post:**

```
    add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', 'my_wp_die_handler_function', 9 ); //9 means         you        can unhook the default before it fires

    function my_wp_die_handler_function($function) {
return 'my_skip_dupes_function'; //use our "die" handler instead (where we won't die)
    }

   //check to make sure we're only filtering out die requests for the "Duplicate"     error we care about
    function my_skip_dupes_function( $message, $title, $args ) {
if (strpos( $message, 'Duplicate comment detected' ) === 0 ) { //make sure we only        prevent death on the $dupe check
   remove_filter( 'wp_die_handler', '_default_wp_die_handler' ); //don't die
    }
   return; //nothing will happen
    }
```